# How can I change the font (not cell!) colour with an IF-condition?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I know how I can change the colour of a cell with the help of [conditional formatting](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=54268). But I would like to use a formula to achieve the following goal.

[image]

If a value `<5.00%` is entered into `A2` **via a formula**, I want it to be displayed in `Red 3`. If it is `>=5.00%`, I would like it to be displayed in `Green 3`. Analogously, the same is true for `A3`/`A4`/`A5` compared with `B3`/`B4`/`B5`.

[`STYLE`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function) is used for background colours.

I have also stumbled upon [this solution](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=34395), but it is suited for text replacement and not for my purpose. After creating two new custom styles, I have tried `=T(STYLE(IF(A2<B2;"Red_if_lesser";"Green_if_greater_or_equal")))`, but it has delivered an error (`Err:522`). What do I have to add to this formula in order to make it work?

Comment: I assume you've put your formula into cell A2. Thus, you've created a circular reference, since the output of your formula is used in the formula itself, modifying it's result. Error code 522 means circular reference. So, you can't use that approach in the case you've described. So, you'll either need to resort to conditional formatting, or you'll have to modify the structure of your calc sheet.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Did you delete your answer? I just wanted to give it an upvote and mark it as the best answer because it worked. But it disappeared.

Comment: Undeleted :-) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For conditional formatting, it doesn’t matter if the cell value is calculated or it’s a fixed value. All you need to do is to define the appropriate rules for conditional formatting. In your case, you'll have to define two rules, one for `current values < plan values`, and one for`current values >= plan values`. To change the font colour, define two new cell styles (can be done inside the conditional formatting dialogue), with an appropriate font colour:

1. Let’s start with the following data:

   [image]
2. Select the cells that should be formatted based on their content. **Pay attention that they are marked in this way:**

   [image]
3. Start defining the conditional formatting:

   [image]
4. First rule: `Cell value is` `less than` `B2` – apply a new style:

   [image]
5. Set the Font Color for the new style in the <kbd>Font Effects</kbd> tab:

   [image]
6. Add another formatting rule using the <kbd>Add</kbd> button – now with green font color:

   [image]
7. Et voilà – the result:

   [image]